# Android: LiteOrm - Objects in List by AbstractClass

Tags: android, orm

I'm beginner in Android and OrmLite (http://ormlite.com/). I have Interface animal:

```
public interface IAnimal {    
    String GetName();
    void SetName(String name);
    String GetBarCode();
    void SetBarCode(String barCode);

}
```

And AbstractAnimal:

```
public abstract class AbstractAnimal implements IAnimal {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    protected Integer id;

    @DatabaseField
    protected String name = null;

    @DatabaseField
    protected String barCode;

    public AbstractAnimal(String name, String barCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

    public Integer GetId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void SetId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String GetName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String GetBarCode() {
        return barCode;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetBarCode(String barCode) {
        this.barCode = barCode;
    }

}
```

And i have group of animals with difrent parameters:

```
public class Tiger extends AbstractAnimal {

    public Tiger(String name, String barCode) {
        super(name, barCode);
    }

}
```

and:
    public class Turtle extends AbstractAnimal {

```
    public Turtle(String name, String barCode) {
        super(name, barCode);
    }

}
```

How to add animals to ZOO?

```
    dbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
    RuntimeExceptionDao<Note, Integer> noteDao = dbHelper.getNoteRuntimeExceptionDao();
    RuntimeExceptionDao<AbstractAnimal, Integer> abstractAnimalDao = dbHelper.getAbstractAnimalRuntimeExceptionDao();

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    abstractAnimalDao.create(new Turtle("Turtle China", "0001"));
    abstractAnimalDao.create(new Tiger("Tiger White", "0002"));


    List<AbstractAnimal> zoo = abstractAnimalDao.queryForAll();
    Log.d("MainActivity", "Count animals in zoo: " + zoo.size() );
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: `zoo.Add(new Turtle("Turtle China", "0001"))` ... ? but it doesn't make sens, as this will be not added to underlaying database ... you are adding it with `abstractAnimalDao.create(...)`

Comment: Hello, thanks, fetching data from database is in another page. For example is in same script